# gmailIntent from static method of a library android project

Tags: android, android-intent, methods, static, gmail

I'm trying to develop a library to approach code in future projects.
I did a way to send an email that it worked.

**Old way (works):**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Hay que hacer un "try" porque si no se ha puesto nada el alguno de los EditText daría un error y se cerraría la app.
    try {
        // Recogemos lo insertado en los campos de texto:
        AD.NAME_LIST = editTextNameList.getText().toString();
        AD.SURNAME_LIST = editTextSurnameList.getText().toString();

        System.out.println("AD.NAME_LIST: "+AD.NAME_LIST);
        System.out.println("AD.SURNAME_LIST: "+AD.SURNAME_LIST);

        dialog.cancel(); // Primero de nada cerramos la ventana de diálogo

        Intent gmailIntent = new Intent();
        gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"); // Usamos directamente gmail
        gmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{AD.EMAIL}); // Dirección de correo electrónico
        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, AD.EMAIL_SUBJECT); // Asunto
        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, AD.SURNAME_LIST+" "+AD.NAME_LIST);  // Cuerpo del e-mail

        try {
            startActivity(gmailIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El e-mail se ha generado correctamente.\n\nSimplemente DALE A ENVIAR.\n\nRecibirás un correo electrónico de confirmación.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El cliente de correo electrónico gmail no está disponible.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No ha rellenado correctamente alguno de los campos.\n\nInténtelo de nuevo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        doorListBtn(v); // Sacamos de nuevo la ventana de diálogo
    }
}
```

**Right now I've done this:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Recogemos lo insertado en los campos de texto:
    AD.names_list[0] = editTextNameList.getText().toString();
    AD.surnames_list[0] = editTextSurnameList.getText().toString();

    System.out.println("Nombre: "+AD.names_list[0]);
    System.out.println("Apellidos: "+AD.surnames_list[0]);

    dialog.cancel(); // Primero de nada cerramos la ventana de diálogo

    // Hay que hacer un "try" porque si no se ha puesto nada en alguno de los EditText daría un error y se cerraría la app:
    try {
        G_A.sendEmailWithNames(getApplicationContext(), AD.EMAIL, AD.EMAIL_SUBJECT, AD.names_list, AD.surnames_list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        G_A.showToast(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "No ha rellenado correctamente alguno de los campos.\n\nInténtelo de nuevo.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        doorListBtn(v); // Sacamos de nuevo la ventana de diálogo
    }
}
```

G_A is an android project library. It has these methodes:

```
/**
 * Envía un e-mail con los nombres y apellidos de la gente que ha sido apuntada.
 * Las casillas de 'names' y 'surnames' se corresponden.
 * @param context
 * @param names Nombres.
 * @param surnames Apellidos.
 */
public static void sendEmailWithNames(Context context, String email, String emailSubject, String[] names, String[] surnames) {
    Intent gmailIntent = new Intent();
    gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"); // Usamos directamente gmail
    gmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email}); // Dirección de correo electrónico
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject); // Asunto
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, names[0]+" "+surnames[0]);  // Cuerpo del e-mail

    System.out.println("email: "+email);
    System.out.println("emailSubject: "+emailSubject);
    System.out.println("names[0]: "+names[0]);
    System.out.println("surnames[0]: "+surnames[0]);

    try {
        context.startActivity(gmailIntent); // Hacemos el intento dentro del contexto de la actividad desde donde se ha llamado
        G_A.showToast(context, "El e-mail se ha generado correctamente.\n\nSimplemente DALE A ENVIAR.\n\nRecibirás un correo electrónico de confirmación.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        G_A.showToast(context, "El cliente de correo electrónico gmail no está disponible.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} // sendEmailWithNames()

/**
 * Muestra un Toast.
 * @param context
 * @param message Mensaje a mostrar.
 * @param duration Tiempo que el mensaje es mostrado por pantalla.
 */
public static void showToast(Context context, String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show();
} // showToast()
```

showToast works, but the other one fails. I think error is just when I call startActivity:

```
context.startActivity(gmailIntent); // Hacemos el intento dentro del contexto de la actividad desde donde se ha llamado
```

But I cannot see logcat error or I'm doing something wrong... I don't know.
PS: G_A class of G_A project is not an Activity.

Comment: I've added as a library G_A project to project where I running the app.

Comment: Fail is sure when I call startActivity(gmailIntent). It is related about context. But I don't find out it yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolve the problem in this way:

G_A method sendEmailWithNames() returns an Intent.

```
/**
 * Envía un e-mail con los nombres y apellidos de la gente que ha sido apuntada.
 * Las casillas de 'names' y 'surnames' se corresponden.
 * @param context
 * @param names Nombres.
 * @param surnames Apellidos.
 */
public static Intent sendEmailWithNames(Context context, String email, String emailSubject, String[] names, String[] surnames) {
    Intent gmailIntent = new Intent();
    gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"); // Usamos directamente gmail
    gmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email}); // Dirección de correo electrónico
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject); // Asunto
    gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, names[0]+" "+surnames[0]);  // Cuerpo del e-mail

    System.out.println("email: "+email);
    System.out.println("emailSubject: "+emailSubject);
    System.out.println("names[0]: "+names[0]);
    System.out.println("surnames[0]: "+surnames[0]);

    try {
        G_A.showToast(context, "El e-mail se ha generado correctamente.\n\nSimplemente DALE A ENVIAR.\n\nRecibirás un correo electrónico de confirmación.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        G_A.showToast(context, "El cliente de correo electrónico gmail no está disponible.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return gmailIntent;
} // sendEmailWithNames()
```

When I call this method from another project, I do this:

```
Intent intent = G_A.sendEmailWithNames(context, AD.EMAIL, AD.EMAIL_SUBJECT, AD.names_list, AD.surnames_list);
startActivity(intent);
```